# Error comparing arrays using deepEqual. What is my mistake and why?

Tags: javascript, deepequals

Can't find why it runs a deepEqual error, and unfortunately I only have this partial error log file. (The test code is not mine).

**Statement:**
We want to write a function suitTrue, which given a suit, returns a list of strings, one for each card of that suit following as truco cards. 
Cards include all numbers except cards 8 and 9.

**My Code:**

```
function SuitTrue(suit) {
  var answer = [];
  for (var i =1; i<8; i++){
    answer.push( i + " of "+ suit);
  }
  for(var i = 10; i<=13; i++) {
    answer.push( i + " of "+ suit);
  }
  return answer;
}
```

**Available teste error:**

```
[ '1 of clubs',
  '2 of clubs',
  '3 of clubs',
  '4 of clubs',
  '5 of clubs',
  '6 of clubs',
  '7 of clubs',
  '10 of clubs',
  '11 o deepEqual [ '1 of clubs',
  '2 of clubs',
  '3 of clubs',
  '4 of clubs',
  '5 of clubs',
  '6 of clubs',
  '7 of clubs',
  '10 of clubs',
  '11 o
```

Comment: There’s no way to answer this with the information provided (although you named your function wrong).

Comment: I don't know how can i edit the post to add this, but the only extra information i have is this: 
This is an exercice in a online course of javascript, the original text and method name are in portuguese so i translated it(if any detail is fuzzy, thats why)...
And the tests they ran only return this message error.

Ps: sorry for not provide the necessary information. =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test they used was wrong, only going up to the twelfth card.

my apologies.